# How large scipy.csr_matrix matrices can be performed by dot product?

Tags: python, scipy

I'm trying to perform dot product with large arrays

```
L_mat=csr_matrix(L_mat)
# L_mat is (24, 1226880)

L_mat_t=csr_matrix(L_mat_t)
# L_mat_t is (1226880, 24)

# Following is possible?
LT_dot_L=L_mat_t.dot(L_mat)
# I'm expecting (1226880, 1226880) but when I did this, 
# I got MemoryError
```

I got same MemoryError when I performed smaller array

```
(523776, 24) dot (24, 523776)
```

This could be performed

```
(24, 523776) dot (523776, 24) = (24, 24)
```

How can I perform large array dot product with csr_matrix or other ways?

Comment: How sparse is this matrix?

Comment: (24, 1226880) is like 3x3 diagonal matrix.
So, 6/9 might be zeros 3/9 has values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not going to try for a memory error, but consider this test

```
In [300]: from scipy import sparse
In [301]: M = sparse.random(10,10000, format='csr')
In [302]: M
Out[302]: 
<10x10000 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 1000 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [303]: M.dot(M.T)
Out[303]: 
<10x10 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 66 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [304]: M.T.dot(M)
Out[304]: 
<10000x10000 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 100310 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Column format>
```

`M` sparsity is 0.01, `Out[304]` is .001, but still there are 100x more nonzero values.  With a (1226880, 1226880) matrix I can easily imagine one that doesn't fit memory, even though it's sparse.

Comment: I tested dot product with (10,10000) shape could be possible. 
But with this large shape of (24, 1226880) ones, it seems not possible.